# Website link on Stack Exchange user profile is linkified even for SPAM accounts

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com

See for example [this user profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2800194/newpath?tab=accounts). The only post I saw from this user on meta was [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181293/100-percent-commission-real-estate-california) (10k+ only).

This user's profile page on Meta and Stack Overflow shows the website as plain text and not a hyperlink - this is by design, and fine in this case. But the profile page on Stack Exchange shows a real clickable link.

[Another example](https://stackexchange.com/users/1886362/laurengreen?tab=accounts) I salvaged from my flags history - this is an old user, so it's not a matter of caching any potential rep.

This is sort of inconsistent, I think the website link should also be plain text on Stack Exchange for users with no rep at all anywhere.

At least part of the Stack Exchange profile page on are indexed by Google, as well as the site profiles. But the link is marked `nofollow` (regardless of rep). So it might be less than a problem than I thought.

Comment: Why? It would be better to have possibility to flag profile as spam. At best to invoice the operator of spam site for the time the users spent with their marketing.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech: that's orthogonal. Website links aren't links anywhere for new users, except on Stack Exchange. That's a good thing and should be extended to Stack Exchange IMO. Flagging profiles is something else completely (and has already been requested/suggested).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Update: As of November 2017, [all Website fields and links in the "About Me" profile sections are unlinked on stackexchange.com, for all users regardless of their reputation on any site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238975/152859). Hence, the below answer is obsolete and the feature request here is obsolete as well.***

---

That's part of [new user restrictions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) which for some reason is not documented.

User with less than 10 reputation will have the link as plain text. [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/174192/skpaik).
User with 10 or more reputation will have the link clickable. [Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/136382/rolf).

The network profile doesn't have reputation of its own.

I think you are correct though, I suggest that unless the user has at least one account with more than 10 reputation, the link will be plain text.

Comment: Your example doesn't work (anymore) and it seems that 10 rep is enough: [example](https://superuser.com/users/790562/), while 9 rep isn't: [example](https://superuser.com/users/533256/)

Comment: @CrazyIvan thanks, I posted this answer before the MSO/MSE split and the auto links conversion didn't pick them up. Also SE fixed the "less than 10" bug at some point, found a new example for that. :)

Comment: Your post's example links no longer illustrate the issue. I tried submitting an edit to update them to new ones which do but [was rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/74772). Want to fix it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I can't fix that, it's impossible to have spam links in the network profile because there are no links anymore there. Just plain text. Your changes made no sense, so I rejected them. You linked to some answer instead of user profile with less than 10 reputation, and to a different user with more than 10 on SO instead of MSE which makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

The links are [no longer linkified for anyone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238975), regardless of their reputation on any account.