# Block video embeds on user profiles

Tags: bug, profile-page

Recently, [links were banned on stackexchange.com user profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238973/de-linkify-links-in-network-profile-if-a-network-wide-suspension-is-applied/238975#238975).

Can we please also prohibit video embeds in all profile pages?

[This spam user](https://stackexchange.com/users/8954320/commercial-truck-finance) has embedded a YouTube link in their profile, which isn't blocked by the link filter for some reason.

I'm honestly sort of surprised that YouTube videos can be embedded at all in a profile. The embed doesn't work on the network sites unless the site allows embedding, though, so it looks like this is specific to stackexchange.com and the list of sites [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/284336). You can see it working on Arqade [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/161237/commercial-truck-finance).

Comment: Ha, that's definitely not supposed to work on Q&A profiles either. Looks like we pass the "about me" markdown through the same pipeline as post markdown gets sent over, which runs the plugins/postprocessors that are enabled on the site... Whoops. Gonna need to fix it up, for sure, though I don't know what the best approach is off the top of my head. (stackexchange.com cares not about any of that, but it receives the processed About Me as-is.)

Comment: I had no idea we can embed videos in profiles. Spammers became smarter than me!! o_O

Comment: I'm... not really sure this question is *about* spam... yes, a spammer made it obvious... but it's asking that it be blocked for **everyone**, not only spammers.

Comment: Agree that [tag:spam] tag is not proper here. /cc @chicks.

Comment: That said, why didn't you just reject the edit? We can now reject suggested edits to our posts even after they are approved.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know. And I was planning to, before Adam did it. I wasn't confident about it, though, so I didn't.

Comment: The main reason we're worried about this bug is because of how it has been and could be exploited by spammers, but I'll defer to the present experts on taxonomy.

Comment: @chicks technically you're correct, and if this was a discussion about that can be done to block the spammer the tag would indeed be perfect fit. However, this is a specific bug report, with scope larger than just spamming. People should not be allowed to embed videos in their profile even if those are valid profiles and videos. (e.g. same way we can't have animated avatars.)