# Links in site profiles stripped from network profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, hyperlinks, network-profile

I have a link in my profile, advertising a Stack Exchange question of mine (which I believe is acceptable use of the profile page). The link works fine on my individual profile pages. For example, [my CG profile](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/users/231/trichoplax?tab=profile) and [my PPCG profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20283/trichoplax?tab=profile). However, on [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/4066709/trichoplax) the links do not show.

The link is present on the GIF and on the text (two separate links, both to the same place). Both work fine on the individual profile pages but both are absent from the network profile page. The GIF and text are present, just without being linked.

Is there a reason for disallowing links from the network profile page, or is this a bug?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a bug; the Markdown has been rendered without a trace of the anchor.

Comment: That only seems to rule out one type of bug. I'm still not sure if that means it's being deliberately or accidentally stripped out.

Comment: I suspect it's an intentional measure that's turned on whenever the network's being spammed.

Comment: It would be nice to know for sure. Has anyone seen links working in network profiles that would suggest this is an intermittent problem?

Comment: Thanks to the many spammers that manage to create lots of accounts the feature to have links in your network profile was dropped. We can't have nice things here. See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746)

Comment: If that's the only reason, I wonder if that restriction could be applied only until a certain reputation is achieved, or only for a limited period of time after first joining?

Comment: @rene No, not a dupe. It's answered there, but the question isn't identical. Please post an answer to this question quoting the answer to that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [De-linkify links in network profile if a network-wide suspension is applied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238973/de-linkify-links-in-network-profile-if-a-network-wide-suspension-is-applied)

Comment: @SonicWizard not really. This is very rare case where a bug report, which is by design, is not duplicate of similar feature request. Reason is the feature request was done **with changes**, that is links are removed for everyone, not only those with suspension. So I don't feel comfortable to close this as dupe. (unless the old feature request is edited to reflect what was really done, which is radical  change, so...)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That question is the official announcement of the change.

Answer (score 5):

This is unfortunately now [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

From Adam Lear's answer on [De-linkify links in network profile if a network-wide suspension is applied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238973/de-linkify-links-in-network-profile-if-a-network-wide-suspension-is-applied)

> As of November 13<sup>th</sup> 2017, all Website fields and links in
>   the "About Me" profile sections are unlinked on stackexchange.com, for
>   all users regardless of their reputation on any site. We can thank the
>   increasing spam activity on the network (a.k.a. The Great Super User
>   Spam Invasion of 2017). So, in other words... this feature request is
>   [status-completed-via-the-nuclear-option](/questions/tagged/status-completed-via-the-nuclear-option).

Based on the comments on that answer I add:

Monica Cello:

> [Is there no practical way to tie it to a rep threshold?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238973/de-linkify-links-in-network-profile-if-a-network-wide-suspension-is-applied#comment986005_238975)

Adam Lear:

> [I do not have the time to bolt a rep (per-site or network-wide) tracker onto stackexchange.com right now. [...] The best we can do at the moment is stop the spam damage and revisit this later if/when the time allows.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238973/de-linkify-links-in-network-profile-if-a-network-wide-suspension-is-applied#comment986008_238975)

Comment: We are also considering removing se.com profiles (in the technical sense - as separate records in a separate database). There's no ETA on doing that, but that's the current line of thinking.

Comment: With that in mind, I've [started a discussion to see whether the community values the network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304229/do-we-want-to-keep-the-network-profile-page). @AdamLear if I've misinterpreted that and only the backend might be changed, with se.com still having profiles just powered differently, then let me know and I'll remove the discussion.

Comment: @trichoplax Last time we talked about it internally, and with the caveat that we might do something different in the end, we were basically going to use the "default" profile from Q&A - that is, what is saved if you edit your profile and have no per-site customizations at all or click "save and copy changes to all sites" or whatever that button is.

Comment: That sounds like the result would look similar to how it is now, and would still have the network wide stats? Perhaps my new meta question is redundant

Comment: AKA: This is why we cannot have nice things.