# Stack Exchange account without site accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, network-profile

[This user](https://stackexchange.com/users/13158256/?tab=accounts) seems to have a Stack Exchange account but no accounts on individual sites in the network:

[image]

I'd expect that for a user whose last account is destroyed, their network account will be as well. For example, [this spammer](https://stackexchange.com/users/13382787) which I just destroyed on Ask Different.

Comment: that one got nuked today by Jnat: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6866531#6866531

Comment: Apparently jnat nuked the foreign key as well ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Shadow explains, these profiles don't always disappear instantly when all the site profiles are deleted and it can take some time (it'll disappear whenever the system attempts to sync their profile info again).

However, it's worth mentioning that it's entirely possible to have a profile on stackexchange.com itself. If you've ever logged in directly there, you have a profile there, as in an actual entry in the database recognizing a user on that site. In fact, it's even possible to register directly on stackexchange.com and start off with a profile there only, without ever having had any site profiles at all. So long as you have a registered stackexchange.com profile, it will never disappear automatically - it requires a staff member to delete it.

As we've continued to move features off of that site, having registered profiles there has become increasingly obsolete, to the point that we [want to get rid of those user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304229/do-we-want-to-keep-the-network-profile-page) and make them truly the automated summaries of the network that most people expect they are. They cause a lot of confusion, particularly among users who delete all their profiles and their stackexchange.com profile just lingers for a month unexpectedly.

Answer (score 5):

This is a result of deleting all network accounts, which is often done for cross network  spammers.

The network profile will be auto deleted at some point, probably up to 24 hours after the last account was removed, unless of course the user will create new accounts.

Comment: Makes sense, but it would make even more sense to destroy the network account immediately. After all, that's what happens with single-site spammers, too, instantly after I destroy them on Ask Different.

Comment: Well, apparently that doesn't affect this [shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/13294179/shog9?tab=accounts)... ([credit to Catija for finding it](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6831861#6831861))

Comment: @Glorfindel problem is, the network account is not a real account, there's nothing really there, it's just a collection/aggregation of the accounts that user has over the network. As such, I believe it can't really be deleted on its own, at least not without complicated low level intervention. (e.g. manual database manipulation)

Comment: @HTTPS huh, nice find... well, we'll see in 24 hours what happens with the account reported in this question. :)