# Links do not appear in the profile info of Stack Exchange profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, hyperlinks

After updating the profile info on Stack Exchange from another SE site, I discovered that the links are not clickable there:

[image: Stack Exchange profile info with not clickable link]

Just for a comparison, here is the same snippet from the About Me section on my Stack Overflow profile:

[image: Stack Overflow - About Me section]

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: This is by design to prevent spam. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238975/284336

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304227/links-in-site-profiles-stripped-from-network-profile?noredirect=1&lq=1