# Web presence link flows through profile info in the network profile

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com, network-profile

I went to the network profile of a certain user, and saw that their web presence link flowed right into their Network Profile info:

[image]

Shouldn't it go to a new line?

Comment: It is one continues "word", so it won't go to a newline. But I agree it isn't very useful in its current form.

Answer (score 5):

It used to be a link, until [spammers abused it one time too much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238975/152859). As a link, it was useful since it could be clicked no matter what part was visible.

Now that it's plain text, when it's cut it's useless.

My suggestion is to move that field *into the About Me box*, as it's just extra info about the user.

Mockup using my own data: (fake details)

[image: mockup of web presence link in About box]

This way there is scrolling in case on non-breakable words, and nothing is lost.

Comment: Yeah, that's good.  Way better than with a new line.