# Are these new accounts simply touting for business?

Tags: support, user-accounts, duplicate-user

This is one of the newly opened accounts:

https://stackexchange.com/users/29091928/the-mike-hostilo-law-firm

There are at least two others from different locations.  They represent a U.S. law firm and appear to be simply looking for business.

I couldn't see any way to flag the new profiles for moderator attention so I've posted it here.

Apparently this is an on-going problem with issues still unresolved.

Comment: [Its an ongoing problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w), that's rather annoying to deal with. Its been going on forever

Comment: Judging from the number of sites they have profiles on, I'm guessing this is a case of SEO spam: creating numerous profiles to get yourself more hits from Google web crawlers.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek On Strike, read your question (up-voted by me) and realise this is a huge, on-going problem.  Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 11):

They're doing it to get their name out there in Google and other search engines (SEO).

Handling these profiles has been put on the back burner before, presumably because they thought it could not actually affect search results. However, that's dead wrong:

[image: Google results showing "spammer" profiles getting Autobiographer badge]

Note that some moderators rename spam accounts "Spammer" and delete on their own site. This is a tedious process and is only as fast as the rate limit allows it to be. It's not really fair to moderators to expect them to do that when these accounts could be deleted en masse from the database. Several [preventative measures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/323179) for this have been suggested as well, but none of them were implemented.